# Plot only Edges with a specific weight - igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have a really large edge list, and I would like to plot only the edges that have a particular weight, how can I do that?

I have so far tried

```
plot.graph(E(sgdf)[E(sgdf)$weight==3]))
```

but I always get this error

```
Error in V(g) : Not a graph object
```

Comment: Do you mean the `igraph` package? Do you mean `plot.igraph`? Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Hmm. There's no package by that name on CRAN (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html#available-packages-I). From where did you download it?

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Copy your graph first, remove the edges that you don't need, and plot the rest:

```
> sgdf.copy <- delete.edges(sgdf, which(E(sgdf)$weight != 3)-1)
> plot(sgdf.copy)
```

The `-1` is needed in `delete.edges` because igraph uses zero-based edge indices while R uses 1-based indices.

**Update**: as an anonymous editor (whose edit was sadly rejected) pointed out, igraph uses 1-base edge indices from igraph 0.6 onwards. Therefore, subtract 1 only if you are using igraph 0.5.x or earlier.